# List and kill at jobs on UNIX

Tags: unix, jobs, kill, solaris-10, at-job

I have created a job with the `at` command on Solaris 10.

It's working now but I want to kill it but I don't know how I can find the job number and how to kill that job or process.

Comment: First do `man ps`.  Read that.  Then update your question based on what you read.

Comment: S.Lott: `at` jobs aren't the same thing as processes though.

Comment: job is running at background , when i run ps -ef i can see some processes running of my commands which my bash script contains that commands , its runnig 15 seconds at once , and proceses ids always changing when i run ps -ef and i could not kill with kill process_id

Comment: what if i restart cron service ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to find your command with a `ps` variant like:

```
ps -ef
ps -fubob # if your job's user ID is bob.
```

Then, once located, it should be a simple matter to use `kill` to kill the process (permissions permitting).

If you're talking about getting rid of jobs in the `at` queue (that aren't running yet), you can use `atq` to list them and `atrm` to get rid of them.

Comment: it s not in queue it s running job every 15 seconds at once

Comment: If you have a process that's kicking on other jobs (new ones every 15 secs), you need to kill the top-level one first, so that behavior stops. That's still using ps to locate it and kill to terminate it.

Comment: top level job is changing too , and getting new id every 15sec

Comment: Then find its PPID and see what process is starting it. Eventually you'll find a long-lived process and that's the one you should concern yourself with.

Comment: i killed ppid of waiting process which is sleep 15 command then , all died.

Answer (score 9):

To delete a job which has not yet run, you need the `atrm` command.  You can use `atq` command to get its number in the at list.

To kill a job which has already started to run, you'll need to grep for it using:

```
ps -eaf | grep <command name>
```

and then use `kill` to stop it.

A quicker way to do this on most systems is:

```
pkill <command name>
```

Answer (score 3):

`at -l` to list jobs, which gives return like this:

```
age2%> at -l
11      2014-10-21 10:11 a hoppent
10      2014-10-19 13:28 a hoppent
```

`atrm 10` kills job 10

Or so my sysadmin told me, and it

Comment: `atrm` doesn't kill running jobs. It only removes them from the queue.

Answer (score 1):

First

```
ps -ef
```

to list all processes. Note the the process number of the one you want to kill. Then

```
kill 1234
```

were you replace 1234 with the process number that you want.

Alternatively, if you are absolutely certain that there is only one process with a particular name, or you want to kill multiple processes which share the same name

```
killall processname
```

Comment: `killall` works on Linux, but do note that on some systems, like Solaris, it actually *kills all processes*, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: Wow, Solaris is DUMB. Why would you ever want to do that? Is like having an alias to 'rm -rf /'